# Access denied when creating a socket under windows xp

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, clr

My application crashes when I try to instantiate a *Socket* or an *IPEndPoint* class under **Windows XP**. Using the DebugView tool, there's a debug log:

> **CLR: Managed code called FailFast, saying " Access is denied. "**

The Windows user is an administrator, I already tried to run as admin (under Run As command), I disabled the firewall, allowed the program in the firewall exceptions but I still can't instantiate.

Even if I try to put the code inside a try/catch block, the program still stop working, it doesn't go to the exception filter.

The program was built with .NET Framework 4.0 and it works fine in other Windows versions.

```
IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("hidden"), port); //crashes the application. Even inside a try/catch block
Console.WriteLine("passed"); //never get executed
```

Comment: what port number are you using?

Comment: 9050 but i don't think it's an port error because it does happens when I try to create a Socket class too (and I don't need to specify a port)

Comment: is your application running in a limited trust?

Comment: Hi, I ran the application under WinDbg and found that the program is trying to load an assembly at C:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32, and that folder doesn't exist in windows xp machines (i forgot to tell that i compiled in a windows 7 x64 machine [any cpu] and i'm trying to run under a windows xp x86 machine)